# How can i store text between "<br>" into a variable in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I have this part of a code:

```
"<div> class="OSInline" style="width: 100%">
<span data-webbtests="CompraWeb.Request_Edit.AddressWB.expCompanyAdress">
Praça Henrique Lavoie Júnior, 701
<br>
Irajá - Rio de Janeiro - RJ - 21231-200
 </span>
/div>"
```

I want to put into a variable the text between br tags like this:

```
Praça Henrique Lavoie Júnior, 701 Irajá - Rio de Janeiro - RJ - 21231-200
```

If I use `storeText` I get this result:

```
Praça Henrique Lavoie Júnior, 701 

Irajá - Rio de Janeiro - RJ - 21231-200
```

Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that:
   Command: storeText 
   Target: css=span 
   Value: your_variable

when you print with echo command, you will see text without break. in my logs:
[info] echo: PraÃ§a Henrique Lavoie JÃºnior, 701 IrajÃ¡ - Rio de Janeiro - RJ - 21231-200

Comment: I see the same, but it depends in what context he's seeing the value with the break in. If you use the stored variable for a 'Type' command, it shows with the break. Felipe can you confirm in what context you're using this stored variable?